# Unexpected behavior for transactions using mongo-go-driver with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, go, transactions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I couldn't get the following simple transaction to work as expected. This behavior is different to all other SO questions I could find.

The following function `MultipleInsertsTransaction()` is inspired by the [official examples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/examples/documentation_examples/examples.go).
It writes one document successfully and then attempts to write a second document, which returns an error, because the same ID is used again (intentionally).

My understanding is, that none of these documents are persisted in the database, as we never reached `sc.CommitTransaction(sc)`, so all operations within `StartTransaction()` and `AbortTransaction()` should be rolled back or rather not even visible to other sessions.

However, that's not the case. The first document is written, the second throws an error as expected, but after the function returned, the first document is persisted in the database.

**What is wrong with this transaction? what am I missing? Or is this even expected?**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readconcern"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/writeconcern"
)

const (
    db = "test"
    coll = "test"
)

func main() {
    client, _ := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("<put replica set connection string here>"))
    want, _ := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).CountDocuments(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if err := MultipleInsertsTransaction(context.Background(), client); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("expected error occured...")
    }
    got, _ := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).CountDocuments(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if got != want {
        fmt.Printf("expected %d entries in database, but got %d", want, got)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("it worked!!")
}

func MultipleInsertsTransaction(ctx context.Context, client *mongo.Client) (err error) {
    return client.UseSession(ctx, func(sc mongo.SessionContext) error {
        err := sc.StartTransaction(options.Transaction().
            SetReadConcern(readconcern.Snapshot()).
            SetWriteConcern(writeconcern.New(writeconcern.WMajority())),
        )
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        id := primitive.NewObjectID()

        if _, err := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).InsertOne(sc, bson.M{"_id": id}); err != nil {
            sc.AbortTransaction(sc)
            return err
        }

        if _, err := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).InsertOne(sc, bson.M{"_id": id}); err != nil {
            sc.AbortTransaction(sc)
            return err
        }

        return sc.CommitTransaction(sc)
    })
}
```

Thanks a lot!

---

I've also tried different implementations, but (as expected) also no luck:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

const (
    db = "test"
    coll = "test"
)

func main() {
    client, _ := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("<put replica set connection string here>"))
    want, _ := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).CountDocuments(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if err := MultipleInsertsTransaction(context.Background(), client); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("expected error occured...")
    }
    got, _ := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).CountDocuments(context.Background(), bson.M{})
    if got != want {
        fmt.Printf("expected %d entries in database, but got %d", want, got)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("it worked!!")
}

func MultipleInsertsTransaction(ctx context.Context, client *mongo.Client) (err error) {
    var session mongo.Session
    if session, err = client.StartSession(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer session.EndSession(context.Background())

    id := primitive.NewObjectID()

    if _, err := session.WithTransaction(ctx, func(sc mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {

        if _, err := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).InsertOne(sc, bson.M{"_id": id}); err != nil {
            sc.AbortTransaction(sc)
            return nil, err
        }

        if _, err := client.Database(db).Collection(coll).InsertOne(sc, bson.M{"_id": id}); err != nil {
            sc.AbortTransaction(sc)
            return nil, err
        }
        return nil, nil
    }); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I've tested your first code snippet (copy pasted) with MongoDB server v4.2.2 and Go driver v1.3.1 and failed to replicate the same issue that you're having.  I created the collection first then ran the code, it throws duplicate key error and nothing is inserted into the collection. Could you make sure there is nothing in the collection to begin with to make sure that the first document was not an existing document in the collection ?

Comment: Thank you @Wan Bachtiar for trying it out, I really appreciate it! My code actually accommodates for the case that there were already documents in the database, since the `want` is read right before the test. I was testing against a azure cosmos replica set. Maybe that’s the issue! I’ll try a raw mongo one as well! Thanks again!

Comment: Completely right. The above code works as expected against a local replica set using docker-compose. So it must be a cosmos thing. I updated the title. Is it a bug on cosmos (especially since it behaves differently than the raw mongo replica set) or a bug?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question title. I've provided an answer, which hopefully gives better understanding on what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure CosmosDB's API for MongoDB is only compatible for [MongoDB Wire Protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) version 3.6. It's emulating the communication to the database, the core database itself is not MongoDB.

[MongoDB multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) is introduced on version 4.0 (currently v4.2). If you're using MongoDB drivers that supports transactions and sending transactional operations, currently CosmosDB would not have the compatibility for it. Depending on your use case, you may find [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/) useful instead.